# Splash screen "scrambles"

Tags: 11.10, unity, installation, shuttle

Trying to install 11.10 to a Shuttle Glamor XPC from a USB. The USB works on other computers, so I know this is just a problem with the Shuttle. Ubuntu splash screen displays, and shows the "loading" dots...then, the screen "scrambles"; "Ubuntu" displays 4-5 times across the bottom of the screen, with entire horizontal lines missing.

I assume this is some sort of video driver issue specific to this computer? I'm running a Shuttle FG31 motherboard, with intel g33/g31 express chipset graphics. The documentation from the ubuntu site says the integrated graphics card is compatible with 11.10, so I'm at a loss.

WindowsXP works fine on this system, without a hint of video card problems.

I've tried booting with `nomodeset`, but no luck.

What's the next step to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does it work otherwise?  Are you able to eventually log in?

Comment: No. It eventually goes to black screen. I found some instructions to boot with "nomodeset", but that didn't work.

Comment: Actually, it seems the system works. I can get to a command line by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F4. But as a noob, I don't know what I need to type. How do find out how the system's graphics are configured, or change it?

Comment: shot in the dark -- I fixed a similar problem by installing gdm, `sudo apt-get install gdm`, running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to select gdm, then removing lightdm (the greeter/user selector that shows up for login).

Comment: Thanks, belacqua, but it tells me "gdm has no installation candidate

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Ok, thanks. My issue was that as somebody new to Ubuntu, I wasn't clear if the problem was the software or was me. So, just to confirm: Ubuntu should install from the boot cd/usb no matter what my system is, and if it doesn't it is a bug?